# Cant use the same customer name twice?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

If I have two customers named John Doe, what do I do? The V3 Qbo API doesn't let me send the same customer name to `/create` twice.

Here's the response if you send the same customer first name / last name combo twice.

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-12-19T18:26:24.966-08:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="6240" element="">
      <Message>Duplicate Name Exists Error</Message>
      <Detail>The name supplied already exists. : Another customer, vendor or employee is already using this
```

name. Please use a different name.

Comment: Not sure what the downvotes are for. It's not inconceivable that I need to invoice two different people with the same name.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect they are because you provided so little information in your question.

Comment: It's a pretty simple question... included an example response to prove you cannot create two customers with the same name.

Comment: I suspect it's a "feature" of bad design choice in the API. Probably need to use a kludgy hack like adding some extra text to the name to differentiate them.

Comment: This is *not* a problem with the API. QuickBooks itself (along with every other major accounting platform out there) *does not allow* duplicate customer names. This is done so that you can easily distinguish, from an accounting perspective, who owes you money and who doesn't, and so you don't confuse the two people with the same name.

Comment: Its fairly likely I'll come across two people with the same name when Invoicing though. QBO tracks invoices by customer. Should I just make John Doe (2)? What is normal here?

Comment: I'm not sure there's really one single "normal" way of handling this. Some people will do "John Doe 2", "John Doe 3", etc.  Other people append a unique customer ID from their own app/db to the customer "John Doe - 12345". Other people will append zip code, or street address, or etc.   If you're building a SaaS app, leave the format of the customer name customizable by your end-user. If it's for a client, ask the client what they want, or talk to the client's accountant and see what the preference is.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation of common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickbook (QBD and QBO) has a unique name constraint across the 3 name entities - Customer, Vendor and Employee. So this API behavior is consistent with the same of product.

Only alternative is to tamper the name of the 2nd entry by adding some meaningful characters or numbers  so that the name becomes unique.

Comment: What if we use RequestId in queryString parameter?
https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2015/04/06/15346

Answer (score 1):

Just tried the API and it does require a unique display name, if you don't specify a display name it will create one based on the prefix first middle last names and suffix

I simply use the suffix field and insert a number then I can choose not to use the suffix later, seem to work

On the API if I get a duplicate record error i increment the suffix number and re-submit